# Reading SAS datasets R sas7bdat package

Tags: r, sas

When reading data sets with 0 or 1 rows into R both show nrow of 1. I need to use the condition to filter out empty data sets in my program. Any idea why the package reads empty SAS data sets with nrow = 1?

Thanks in advance.

Regards
K

Comment: Can't do much investigation since most of us have no facilities for constructing a test case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have to use the sas7bdat package?  Can you use `haven` instead?

```
> library("haven")
> read_sas("c:/downloads/empty.sas7bdat")
# A tibble: 0 x 5
# ... with 5 variables: Name <chr>, Sex <chr>, Age <dbl>, Height <dbl>, Weight <dbl>
> read_sas("c:/downloads/one.sas7bdat")
# A tibble: 1 x 5
  Name   Sex     Age Height Weight
  <chr>  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Alfred M      14.0   69.0    112
>
```

Comment: Hi Tom, Thanks a lot. I ended up using "haven" package. It works. Regards.